# Does the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" error cause any security problems?

Tags: java, jvm, buffer-overflow, android-security, java-security

recently a user in our program also encountered the following error and reported to us:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3029656 byte allocation with 2838072 free bytes and 2MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456`

I've found that this error is causing a DoS.
Do you think attackers can benefit from this error? (Like buffer overflow.)

I'm new to Java and waiting for your comments.
Thanks.

Comment: An attacker can benefit from a DoS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about security in software

Answer (score 0):

No, Java is designed to be secure, that's why it runs in Virtual Machine.

For example, it is possible to overflow a buffer in Clang and overwrite memory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Buffer_overflow_protection

> Languages that are strongly typed and don't allow direct memory access, such as COBOL, Java, Python, and others, prevent buffer overflow from occurring in most cases.

Comment: Hm, you probably should revise your answer, since [oracle itself publishes a big list of recommendations](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html) to consider to keep JVM applications save, aside running on the jvm.